# Is there a class in AS3 that tells you the type of the URL protocol?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

Is there a class in AS3 or Flex that tells you the type of protocol a URI or URL is part of? I was sure there was a class that broke a URL into various parts and grouped it into usable data.

For example, if the URL is, "mailTo" it would return "mail" protocol. Or if the URL is "http://www.google.com" it would return "url" protocol. Something along those lines.

Comment: Probably split the string by `:` and switch-case the left side will provide you the necessary data.

Comment: That's like what I'm doing now, `url.indexOf("http")==0.` But this seems fragile and if new protocols have been added I don't know about maybe this class has them all listed.

Comment: So you need a list of protocols? [Check here](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=URI_scheme), there's a pretty big list in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [URLUtil](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/URLUtil.html) in the Flex library.